# Am I being scammed? (UK visit visa refusal)

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, family, scams

I am from Pakistan. I applied for a 4 week UK family visit visa with my 6 year old daughter and they refused, my refusal issue is the same. I am going to quote my refusal letter:

[[image: Refusal Letter]

These objections and reasons are not as like they thinking I have my bank statement and transactions including Rs. 4 lac balance I have transactions of my salary in statement and my husband recently employed he is also have his salary transaction in the same statement because we are both using our joint account.

I just want to go to the UK and meet my family for 4 weeks and I am with my 6 year old daughter. My husband is not going with us due to his job.

Now please guide me; should I go for an Administration review and provide them my bank statement because my visa was rejected on 26 July 2016 I still have time period for administration review OR should I reapply immediately to remove all these objections and give them more evidences I mean bank statements and our pay slips etc? Kindly guide me what to do which way will work. Your quick help and guidelines will help me.

Comment: Did you supply bank statements with your application?

Comment: No I dont Give My Bank Statement My sponsors shown there own and this case were quoted by a Solicitor in the UK he told that I dont need to submit my own bank statement as my sponsors stated that they will afford all my travel expenses etc. I have my bank statement which is clearly shown my salary and my husband's salary transactions and our savings balance upto PK 4 hundred thousands..

Comment: I would like to mention the documents that I gave them with my aand my daughters application 
1. My Employer Letter 
2. My Spouse Employer Letter
3. My Daughter School Leave Certificate 
4. Our Marriage Certificate 
5. My Husband's Passport  Copy
6. My Original Passport 
7. My Daughter's Passport
8. Our Family Life Style Photographs
9.  Sponsors Letter 
10.  Sponsos Passtport Copy 
11. Sponsors Mortage Documents 
12. Sponsors Property Docuemnts which is in the UK 
13. Sponsors 6 Months Bank Statement. 

These documents were submit with application and visa got refused in 15 days

Comment: Please [edit your other post](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/76122/edit) instead of asking the same thing again as a new question. Your other question was already answered [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/32134) - if that does not answer your question, edit to point out why and why your case is different, with specific details and show that you have actually read the duplicate. And do not add details in comments, edit!

Comment: Now suggest me If I reapply which documents should be added to clarify and remove previous objections and doubts. They satisfied with my sponsor but the only single reason they dont satisfied with my and my spouse employment status. for mpre details please read above refusal letter and Guide me also how long will be good to reapply as my visa got refused on 26 July 2016 and I received back my passport on 2 August 2016.. Thanks

Comment: Why do you keep asking about administrative review?  Asking about it again and again does not make it magically appear.  It makes me wonder if perhaps you are being scammed.  Did someone offer to submit an administrative review on your behalf?

Comment: Dear Gayot Fow Actually My solicitor wants to take administrative review he said everything is okay we just need to show bank statement with administrative review where is clearly salary transactions we dont need to reapply , I am not getting satisfied whatever administrative review will work or not I need your suggestions because you wrote that visitor cant take administrative review but my solicitor going to do this I am confused. Please help me to clear this confusion :/

Comment: The likelihood here is that you are getting scammed. Your narrative fits a well-known profile of how scammers in South Asia are known to operate. I will ask the community to reopen your question on that basis.

Comment: You Mean I should reapply instead to go for administrative review? and also appoint a different solicitor?

Comment: @ABc I believe it would still be great if you could post a scan of your refusal notice with the personal details blacked out. Also you should consider accepting the answers you get to your questions, by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer, under the arrows for voting. And of course you should also upvote helpful answers that you get by clicking on the up-arrow to the left of the answer, over the number.

Comment: yes, please read the above comment by @mts and then read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers because courtesy is also important. This site is not a forum

Comment: Ok Sorry I dont find any folder to attach my scanned refusal notice if you guide how I post my refusal notice in this post?

Comment: @ABc why are you rolling back people's changes? You changed the title to shouting, which we don't like, and now it makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry Gayot Actually I want To Reapply and need guidelines instead to go for lengthy discussions therefore I attached my refusal letter. sorry once again

Comment: Regarding the last bullet point on refusal reasons, you didnt really try and claim a Visa refusal breaches your human rights, did you?!

Comment: @Moo - it looks like the claim was made that as family were being visited, refusal of a visa would amount to denial of a family life. Which is A) clearly nonsense (the family member in the UK could just visit home) and B)likely guaranteed a refusal, as it implied that the applicant **does** wish to live in the UK, which would be in breach of a visit visa.

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate. It deals with a specific issue (administrative review) that is not covered by the main question.

Answer (score 34):

The likelihood here is that you are getting scammed. Your narrative fits a well-known profile.  In comments you wrote...

> Actually My solicitor wants to take administrative review he said
> everything is okay we just need to show bank statement with
> administrative review where is clearly salary transactions we dont
> need to reapply , I am not getting satisfied whatever administrative
> review will work or not I need your suggestions because you wrote that
> visitor cant take administrative review but my solicitor going to do
> this I am confused.

And this is the pattern...

1. You apply for a Standard Visitor Visa and get refused
2. A 'lawyer' offers to provide representation in an Appeal or an
   Administrative Review. His representation may or may not attract a fee in the opening gambit.
3. You Google for 'Administrative Review' and see that it's a real
   thing.
4. You pay because you are very disappointed about the refusal
5. A few weeks later the lawyer tells you there's great news! Your case
   was reviewed and will be handed over to the Tribunal for a decision,
   but his representation will attract a fee. You pay.
6. A few weeks later the lawyer tells you there's great news! Your case
   was heard at the Tribunal and will be brought before the Upper
   Tribunal, but his representation will attract a fee. You pay.
7. And so on until the lawyer tells you that a fresh application is
   needed, and his representation will attract a fee, blah blah blah.

Each step is supported by correspondence and paperwork from the 'Home Office'. But... It's all fake.

And here's why...

The Standard Visitor Visa has no rights of appeal or administrative review.  Administrative Review has to do with other kinds of visa applications, stuff like work permits and entrepreneur visas.  So it's a scam.  Somebody can say, "HEY, the lawyer is innocent, he just doesn't know how things work"; that's tantamount to a scam anyway.

Taking a closer look at your refusal notice...

[image]

From the [Home Office's web site](https://www.gov.uk/ask-for-a-visa-administrative-review/if-youre-outside-the-uk) (emphasis mine):

> #### 1. If you're outside the UK
>
> You'll be told in your application refusal letter if you can ask for the decision on your visa application to be reviewed. This is known as an 'administrative review'.
>
> You can only ask for an administrative review if **all of the following apply:**
>
> - you're outside the UK
> - you applied outside the UK
> - your application was refused on or after 6 April 2015
> - you don't have a right of appeal against the refusal
> - **you didn't make an application as a visitor or short term student**

On the plus side, you may not actually have a refusal, it depends upon where the scam took root.

Best practices advice follows three pathways undertaken simultaneously:

1. Do not apply again right away
2. Initiate a "[Subject Access Request](https://ico.org.uk/for-the-public/personal-information/)" to get your file and see what
   the 'official' records say about you.
3. When your SAR comes back, arrange a consultation with a member of the [UK Law Society](http://www.lawsociety.org.uk/), use  the lookup tool on [ILPA](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/search-directory.php).

Comment: There's a great film in theatrical release, "High Strung" where one of the character arcs shows this scam in operation. Recommended film. It takes place in NYC, but the scam is really popular in South Asia and Central Africa.

Comment: +1 -- this is some excellent guidance. I bet many people don't know that there is no right to appeal for visit visas!

Comment: @DavidRicherby, grateful for your edit; please consider that their links change nearly every year as does their text. The image 'captures' and freezes the moment in time and keeps it contemporary to this site's content.

Comment: @GayotFow Sure, but presenting the material as text also captures and freezes the moment in time, while being accessible to search engines and the visually impaired.

Answer (score 4):

The refusal letter itself states that:

> In relation to this decision there is no right of appeal or right to administrative review

Therefore you should not attempt administrative review, as it is not available. Any solicitor telling you that is their plan should be dropped immediately, as they are clearly incompetent and incapable of reading plain English at best.

As such, the only approach you could take would be to reapply. If you are doing so, then you should carefully read these official UK government pages regarding what is required and expected of you:

[Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) - note that this is the visa you should be using for a 4 week visit. Family visas are for those looking to stay more than 6 months.

[Visitor Guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424265/VAF1-GUIDANCE-NOTES.pdf) - help from the UK govt on applying for a visitor visa.

However, you should note that your refusal states that:

> ... you are likely to be refused unless the circumstances of your application change.

This implies that the problem with your application (from the point of view of the people deciding to award you a visa) is your personal situation, and not the evidence (or lack thereof) that you have provided. You can apply again with better evidence, but unless your existing evidence is misleading in some way, the ECO thinks you will be refused again.

Comment: CMaster Thank you so much finally you gave me the answer which I wanted thanks I am going to reapply again and will use same papers with the additional evidences which were not provided last time. Please also give me best regards I wants to get visa this time because everything is clear I dont LIE or tried to hide anything I have my savings and Job status evidences pay slips salary transactions good balance bank statement etc the only mistake was I trusted my solicitor and followed his guidelines for not providing bank statements at my end and this was the main mistake and reason of my refusal

Comment: I am a female and married I intend to travel to my family with my little 6 years daughter my husband will be in Pakistan he is not going with us so I will be back to Pakistan for my husband because I cannot leave my husband alone for long  as visa officer thinking I may not come back which is nonsense becouse without a husband life could not be a life :( so I just needed to satisfied them in my next application.

Comment: @ABc - you don't have to convince me, you have to convince the ECO (Entry Clearance Officer). Make sure if you are applying again to read all of the actual guidance, and not to listen to anyone who advises you against it (eg those who say not to include bank statements). Do be prepared for disappointment though. Read this too: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: @CMaster *"Do be prepared for disappointment though"*, you can double down on this and substitute "habituated" for "prepared" and still be correct. +1 by the way.

Comment: Thank you soo much for amazing guidelines I learn alot from here and had some good guidelines too for which I am very thankful to you all. I am just asking my last question If someone dont have any property on her name so what she will have to do? I read on the Visa immigration website they mentioned property documents requirements too after the bank statements

Comment: If you've got a further question, please press the "Ask a new question" button in the top right and ask it.