# UK Visit Visa refused second time due to lack of funds and unclear documentation. What are my options?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-employment

[image: Refusal notice page 2]

My UK visit visa was refused again. I applied for UK visit visa this July with my 6 years daughter the visa was sponsored by my aunt and uncle both are British nationals.

But my visa was refused due to financial capacity, I didn't submit my bank statements and pay slips and property proof etc. I was wrongly guided by an solicitor that your trip is sponsored so you don't need to show your own statements etc as your sponsors paying for all your expenses. However the guide was totally wrong which led to a refusal.

After that I applied again last week 19 September 2016 from Islamabad, Pakistan and attached all documents: my daughter's school leave approval letter, employer letter, my pay slips of 6 months, my bank statements with balance (GBP3000) my property documents worth (GBP34,000) value also lease agreement of my property monthly income (GBP370) along with rent receiving proofs, my tax return certificates for year 2016, travel itinerary which clearly shown trip of 1 month trip, family registration certificate, along with cover letter visit purpose is to meet my aunt and uncle and visit different places in UK. I mentioned names also in the letter following documents attached with my second attempt

- Visa Application Form of my daughter and myself
- Passport of my daughter and myself
- Passport copy of my husband
- Marriage Certificate and Family Registration Certificate
- My Daughter School leave approval letter
- Employer letter of my husband and myself
- Personnel Bank Statement reflecting salary transfer and Salary slips of my   husband and myself
- Personnel Property documents and property lease agreement
- Personnel Tax returns
- Travel itinerary
- Sponsorship Statements
- Six Months Bank Statements of sponsors
- Tax Certificate of Sponsors

I have attached second refusal please read and guide me this refusal really heard me what are the reason of refusal after having read all my story?

Comment: The highlighted section says nothing about property. It's saying that they'd like to see bank statements or similar showing payments that match the claimed salary in the letter. A letter from an employer is after all, easy to fake.

Comment: The information in the refusal letter seems to indicate that you stated that your family receives your salary, your husband's salary, and the income you receive from renting property. Do you bank statements indicate all this income? Everything should match up: if you claim a certain income on the form, the same amount should appear as a deposit every month in your bank statements and the documents you submit should verify this amount. If you claim your spouse's income or rental income on the form and it never appears in your bank statements, they will rightly be suspicious.

Comment: Dear CMaster, My spouse salary is 52,800PKR and company deducting some tax from  total salary my spouse receiving his salary after deduction by company and the net received salary is matching with his pay slips were clearly shown every thing total salary, amount of tax deduction and payable amount I have attached his pay slips not alone employer letter so I dont understand why ECO saying you submitted just only one employer letter etc even payslips of my spouse were also attached which clearly matched with bank statement.

Comment: Dear Zach Lipton, I was aware of everything and the income I claimed in application clearly match with my bank statements each month there is no doubt between attached proofs claimed income and bank statement deposits. this is what I am saying if everything are okay then why ECO object these all??  its really heart me I am just loosing my heart to see this refusal. because I provided each and everything accurate as per claimed info ..

Comment: @ABc - There's a lot of documentation attached. It has been known for VFS to remove documents before passing on the decision centre.

It's also worth noting that even if you resolve these documentation issues "I am not satisfied of your intentions to visit the UK at this time" and "however you are likely to be refused unless your personal circumstances change" IE: even if everything you have told them is accurate and true, they aren't going to let you in.

Comment: @CMaster,I dont understand this at all as I told them I want to visit my aunt and visit some places in UK which are very interesting to me visiting family and visit your dreamy places should not need further justifications. however as per your opinion if in future  after 1 year  if I wished to reapply for the 3rd attempt what changes will effect to remove all this you read in refusal? there is any best way to satisfied thm that I am a genuine visitor just want to visit UK once a life to see my dreamy places n will return back to my home country. please guide me as per your best experience. Thx

Comment: @CMaster But does "personal circumstances" mean *claimed* personal circumstances or *demonstrated* personal circumstances?  By my reading, it is the latter; if that is true then the "even if..." comment does not make sense.

Comment: You need to **hire a solicitor**.  It's just that simple.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for uploading your refusal notice, it's not necessary to amend it with margin notes (we're not the Tribunal), but we take your point.  They spotted a proportionality issue and it damaged your credibility.

This pattern doesn't make a lot of sense.  In your previous refusal, now entitled [Am I being scammed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76149/am-i-being-scammed-uk-visit-visa-refusal)?  You were using a scam artist or someone unqualified to provide advice services.  They were leading you down a contrived  path about lodging an administrative review when no such pathway exists. Your advice at that time was...

> When your SAR comes back, arrange a consultation with a member of the
>   [UK Law Society](http://www.lawsociety.org.uk/), use the lookup tool on [ILPA](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/search-directory.php).

This clearly didn't happen because a qualified person would have picked up on the proportionality issue vis-a-vis your previous refusal right away and put the brakes on. Your second application was not going to succeed and should have been postponed.  The operative statement in both refusals is...

> Any future UK applications you make will be considered on their
>   individual merits, however you are likely to be refused unless the
>   circumstances of your application change.

This time you gave a lot more evidence and they agreed that your relatives are OK for sponsorship, but nothing really changed about *YOU* did it?  All of the stuff you submitted still reflects the same circumstances as your previous application. For example, you are financially dependent, and  still reliant on cosponsors and still spending a disproportionate amount of your reserves for a visit.

I really like [CMaster's](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster) [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80107/uk-visit-visa-refused-second-time#comment182260_80107) about the VFS situation in South Asia where  courrier personnel are removing evidence from an applicant's bundle. This is true and is a topic of on-going concern and worry for practitioners, but your narrative seems to show that all of your evidence was accounted for.

Your question is...

> I have attached second refusal please read and guide me this refusal
>   really heard me what are the reason of refusal after having read all
>   my story?

They got you on Appendix V 4.2 (a) & (c), which essentially means there's a good chance you will abscond your visa and go underground and probably become reliant upon public funds.  It's a very common refusal for co-sponsored applications (especially for applicants in South Asia because of the preponderance of historical performance issues) that are weak to begin with, we have a lot of these in the archives here.

You're in a situation of serial refusals, it's advisable to stop applying at the moment and that your next application be represented by a qualified solicitor.

---

And just for the record about your bank statements. You need to submit them even if you are being sponsored by relatives.  It's fundamental advice that bank statements are part of every weak applicant's evidence because they help the decision-maker reach an informed and fair decision. See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) for a lengthy discussion about it.

---

Adding: The refusal notice mentions the name of a Pakistani bank **explicitly**. That usually means it shows up on one of the lists they keep. Or it might mean nothing at all, but it might be worthwhile to see if other people using statements from the same bank are having similar problems making visa applications to Europe. See http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/8/contents

Comment: Gayot Thank you for your detailed and advisable answer. My last question should I change my Bank? Should I open a separate account in a well reputed bank because they also highlighted joint account point with my spouse? or if next time me and my spouse both apply should we both submit our separate  bank statements or a joint account statement will be enough if we apply together? and in the end if we avoid getting help from our sponsors and bear all expenses of our visit at our hand just mention accommodation facility from sponsors that will be okay?  Please advice for fixing an idea