# I have had five prior UK visa refusals, should I still apply for UK tourist visa?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, serial-refusals

I am from India. I visited the UK twice in 2003, when I was 19 and playing cricket there. Although initially refused, the team manager made arrangements and we received 6-month multiple entry visas. The first visit was 12 days and, a month later, I returned and stayed for 2 1/2 months.

Since then, however, I have had 5 refusals; I was single, didn't provide information on what I was doing, or couldn't show sufficient funds.

I am planning to apply once again and want to go for a 2-week visit . I am married, have a one-year-old daughter, and began working for a company in 2013.  I have 90000 in my bank and can provide salary slips and NOC. My salary is 18000 which goes into my account. My wife works and is paid 26000; her checks are deposited in her bank account. My wife and child won't accompany me.

Should I apply for the UK tourist visa or not ? I do not have the previous refusal letters; how would I get those? After getting so many UK refusals, I cannot apply for any other country.

Comment: You can apply for visas elsewhere - but much of the rest of "the west" will indeed know about your UK refusals.

Comment: *I have 90000 in my bank*.  In what currency?  Also, what is your citizenship?

Comment: Why? What is the purpose of your visit to the UK?

Comment: @NateEldredge based on his name I suppose he's from India, and the monetary unit is rupee

Comment: Also, is that salary per week / month / year / ?

Comment: The UK is an incredibly expensive place to visit for someone earning £220/month. Why not pick somewhere cheaper, hotter, and friendlier.

Comment: ₹90000 is about £1000 - if you stay in the cheapest hostels you might get away with £300 or so for lodging for two weeks, leaving you £700 to do things (assuming you don't need that money to pay for flights to/from the UK).  That's really not a lot unless you plan to see free sights, cook your own meals, etc.  They will probably want to see at least £100/day in excess of lodging, so probably closer to £1800 total would be needed to convince someone you could afford the visit.  I'd probably spend 9 months' salary doing something else, to be honest...

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: We expect the author of the question to provide these details, in the question (rather than having to guess based solely on someone's name). That's what Nate is inviting Ranjeet to do. Only Ranjeet can satisfy that request.

Comment: Dude, good on you for saving 5x your salary but you can't afford this trip.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oddly enough, the original revision said "This is Ranjeet .. from India", and that was edited out.

Comment: Is it possible to retroactively reject the unhelpful edit?  That was important information, that the editor removed.

Comment: @muru: Heh, I see! That shouldn't have been removed :) Just waiting for confirmation of the currency then so we can edit that in too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply for UK visit visa after four refusals?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81668/how-to-apply-for-uk-visit-visa-after-four-refusals)

Comment: *I have 90000 in my bank* presumably you mean INR, you need to add that. It's better to state amounts in GBP. The GBP-INR rate since 2016 varies from 89-98. £1000 is not a lot. If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 55):

Normally we need to see a scan of the refusal notice, but five of them obviates that requirement. Your situation has moved on from a "plain vanilla" refusal.

An unbroken sequence of five refusals indicates that you are in a 'serial refusals' tailspin.  Part of this situation means that they are no longer able to consider applications on their merit because the history has taken on a life of its own. I.e., that your fixation on getting to the UK has convinced them that you are not a genuine applicant. Or to put it more bluntly, genuine applicants will either resolve the issues on the second or third attempt or they will find some other place to visit and move on with their life.

You need to start being a little bit careful because if they get the idea that your applications are frivolous, they can issue a ban ([Paragraph 320, subparagraph 11 (iv)](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal) "*...making frivolous applications...*").  It's their recourse against people who appear to be obsessed or in some other way 'disturbed'.  We had one of those here a few weeks ago demonstrating that bans are accumulated *consecutively* rather than concurrently. So be thinking about that factor before jumping in again.

> I am planning to apply once again and want to go for a 2-week visit.

Why? The cure for serial refusals from the UK is invariably to build up a track record of performance in the affluent Commonwealth (Canada, Australia, NZ and so on) along with other non-Commonwealth countries like the USA, Japan, and Ireland.  Schengen experience can be helpful also.

> I do not have the previous refusal letters; how would I get those?

You can submit a [Subject Access Request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration) by writing to the Home Office at 2 Marsham St, London SW1P 4DF, United Kingdom. The Information Commissioner has thoughtfully provided [a sample template on his site](https://ico.org.uk/media/for-the-public/documents/1253/how_to_make_a_request.doc) (an MS Word Document).  Usually they will not release the refusal notices themselves (at least in my experience) because it's not in the public interest, but will provide an extract or summary (if they honour the request in the first instance).

> Should I apply for the UK tourist visa or not?

It's a matter of opinion.  What is not a matter of opinion is that you need representation by a member of the [Law Society](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/), and they won't even *think about it* without seeing your refusal history. Since you do not have those and are about a year away from getting anything, it doesn't make a lot of sense does it?

> I cannot apply for any other country.

This is wrong. A lot of people with refusal histories think they need to 'clear their name' before they can move on with their life. But there is nothing preventing your filing an application to Thailand, Russia, Vietnam, Kazakhstan, and other countries in that area. Peripatetic history of any sort is always helpful.

---

NOTE: I assume you are South Asian and your currency is denominated locally. More to the point, those things do not matter in this case.

Comment: Great answer; I was wondering what you mean by "you need representation by a member of the Law Society"? What part of this situation necessitates having a lawyer?

Comment: @knowah people should get a solicitor after the 1st refusal, after the 2nd it's pretty much hopeless without one. I am not optimistic that the OP will be able to instruct one however.

Comment: Even if the five refusals weren't in and of themselves damning, clearly the OP is missing some key aspect(s) of applying for a visa and needs some professional advice on how to write a better application.

Comment: @GayotFow: a great answer, as usual (+1) - is it possible to provide a minimum estimate how much this would cost OP? This might be helpful in evaluating the priorities in case the cost is high; assuming he's talking about 90,000 INR in bank, that's slightly over 1000 GBP - and my impression is that UK solicitor would cost way, way more than that alone.

Comment: @GeorgeY. fair question IF a solicitor would take the case and I don't see that happening. They would get into trouble for opportunism not to mention a damaged reputation on the street for exploitation. The OP doesn't have his own paperwork FFS, if he instructed a solicitor to manage ONLY his SAR I would guess about GBP 2.5k, but that's before even the first mention of an application. It's just not going to happen, sorry.

Comment: What does *"representation by a member of the Law Society"* mean? must be a UK immigration lawyer? Not an Indian lawyer? Could you be more specific about what types of lawyer handle these situations?

Comment: @smci, no, that's a different question altogether. Immigration services are massively regulated per the Immigration and Asylum Act 1999.  You would need to ask a new question to cover that area, sorry...

Comment: @GayotFow: It's not my question, I'm not the OP; I was simply pointing out that this answer is unclear, and people (esp. non-UK residents) may find this advice costly. Are you actually saying that non-UK lawyers are not allowed to write appeals (I doubt that), or just that they won't get taken seriously? ('India lawyer uk visa refusal appeal' has 883K hits on Google.) Do you have a source to confirm that?

Comment: @smci if you add 'scam' to your google search terms you get 9+ million hits, more than 10 times your results. The OP is more vulnerable to scam operators who will promise to fix everything more than anything else right now. The answer has to remain 'as is', sorry. If you are unsatisfied, you can raise a new question about why I only link to regulated organisations. Or take it up in META, or whatever.

Comment: @GayotFow: the issue is not that you only link to regulated organizations; the issue is that you only referenced UK organizations, and you insinuated non-UK lawyers could not help with the appeal; moreover since the OP was not a UK-resident. The onus is on the person making the claim (you) to back it up, not on me to rebut it. Anyway I suspect you're correct but it's hard to find citations to support that, even on gov.uk. But here's one [10 Mistakes... When Applying For UK Visa](http://crossborderlegal.co.uk/content/immigration-lawyers-uk-best-immigration-lawyers-in-uk-human-rights-solicitor/)

Comment: Also, there are two different ways: 'appeal' (the common one) and 'judicial review' (harder).

Comment: @smci appeal is not an option for visit visas. Only scam operators will tell you that it is. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76149/am-i-being-scammed-uk-visit-visa-refusal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47663/discussion-between-gayot-fow-and-smci).

Answer (score 10):

First, the reason for your visit may not be clear this time. The first one was a group visa with cricket members, but this time it's individual visa. They may believe that you are not going to return back if granted a visa.

Secondly, you have been in the UK twice before, so there is no reason to keep applying to come back. Instead, try applying for other countries and give it time before making another application.

In your application what is the purpose of visit (tourist, visiting family or relatives, friends)? What makes you want to return to visit and where in UK (London, Manchester, Scotland etc.)? How long is your stay (2 weeks, months)? Also, why UK and not anywhere else?

Comment: +1 for 'why UK and not anywhere else'. A good premise is key critical!

Comment: @GayotFow I apologize for deleting that OP is 'dying to see that beautiful place once more and later want to show it to me family.'

Comment: @Dorothy: Sounds like an attempt to obtain a visa by _flattery_. This can only end badly.

Comment: @HenningMakholm indeed; and about the same odds as winning the lottery.