# Family Visit Round 3

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, family

I am an Egyptian citizen, married to a British citizen. I applied for the family visit visa and got two refusals a year ago. I have 62,500 sterling in my bank account and it has been there for over 8 months. I was planning to apply for the spouse visa but now I have a job, directing a production in a university in Egypt in the fall. Would it be wise to reapply for the family visit visa now, to be able to go in the summer, and then apply for the spouse visa when I'm done with my job?

Comment: A bank account is more than just a bank balance and you can find an in depth look here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105. It appears you are engaged in **funds parking**, although that's debatable considering its been 8 months. After two rejections you're getting close to a state called a  tail-spin of 'serial refusals' https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81668/how-to-apply-for-uk-visit-visa-after-four-refusals/81673#81673. Finally the last part of your question is opinion based.