# Refused Entry to UK via Paris France

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, canadian-citizens

My mom (Canadian) was coming over to visit me in London UK via Paris. She was already here for 5 months, went home for a month, and then was coming back to use my place as a "base camp" as she went travelling back and forth to mainland europe. When she got to immigration at the Eurostar the UK border control didn't let her through and did biometrics on her and a 2 hour interview. Now she is stuck in France but her passport doesn't say how long she can stay there and we need to know how she can enter the UK, what type of visa doses she need if she has been refused entry?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: She can be in the Schengen area for a total of 90 days in any 180-day period. We can't really answer the UK question workout knowing the reasons she was given for being refused entry. Please edit them into your question.

Comment: We need to know the reason for the refusal in order to provide a quality answer. Hence why the question is currently on hold.

Answer (score 1):

She can stay in the Schengen area of which France is part for [90 days](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf) in every successive 180 day period. She can return to Canada and apply for a standard visitor visa however her chances of getting it in the immediate term are slim. She failed her landing interview, likely for the reason below. I had a similar [six hour ordeal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-uk-previously-refused-should-i-apply-fo/89879#89879) interview with UK immigration but ultimately passed and was let in. The secret to passing landing interviews is to be adequately prepared, just like you would be for a visa interview with supporting documents etc.

[Immigration Rules Appendix V: visitor rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)

> **Genuine intention to visit**
>
> V 4.2 The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a
>   genuine visitor. This means that the applicant: (a) will leave the UK
>   at the end of their visit; and (b) **will not live in the UK for
>   extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK
>   their main home**;

I similarly use the UK as my base for European travel and planned an entry through Calais this past May which I ultimately changed and came to the UK direct. The best advice will be return to Canada or redo her travel plans to be feasible without having a base. Of course she can attempt to enter again tomorrow without a visa via the same route or by air via another route or sea, nothing precludes her from doing so. Nevertheless the chances are slim and she can be banned from entering the UK after another or subsequent attempts so she should be careful.

You do not want to get into a [tail spin of successive refusals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81589/i-have-had-five-uk-visa-refusals/81596#81596).